# Xml parsing exception on relative path with Eclipse gdb DSF debug

Tags: c++, eclipse, gdb

I'm using Eclipse Mars, with gdb 7.2.

**While trying to debug a C++ application in Eclipse gdb DSF, I'm getting a parse exception. But I don't get the parse exception when I run the same program with gdb outside of Eclipse.**

The exception states: **"Fatal error during XML Parsing: unable to open primary document entity /path/to/file.xml"**

But the actual path in xml is a relative path:  "../../../../path/to/file.xml". 
The C++ application is reading in the XML and trying to open this file.

It's as if the ../..'s are just getting chopped off, and that's why the error states essentially "I don't know about a /path/to/file.xml"

I imagine that something is wrong with my gdb setup in Eclipse, but I'm not sure what. I've tried many different things, none of which seem to work.

I imagine that this has something to do with relative paths not being recognized by gdb, or the working path being different in Eclipse vs gdb.

Does anyone have an idea what is wrong?

Comment: When using eclipse the path would be `/your_workspace_path/your_project_name`.

Comment: There is not enough information here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, this was a simple issue: It turns out that my Working Directory(in Debug Configurations under the Arguments tab) had to be set to the full path of the location of my executable.

I also had to set the path of my executable to the full File System path of the executable.

It works as expected now.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure the Working Directory matches the location of the executable in the File System.

https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Working-Directory.html